# How to host on GitHub Pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

I have followed many tutorials on how to host via GitHub Pages and well I can't get it to work. Git confuses me alot because I push my html to my gh-pages branch and after an hour my site still didn't work.

How can I fully set up a site using GitHub Pages?

Comment: Do you have the link to your repo?

Comment: https://github.com/ZoidinCode/ZoidinCode.github.io @jianweichuah

Comment: Move index.html out of the folder

Comment: What branch do I use?  @jianweichuah

Comment: Since this is your main page, master. gh-pages is used for sub pages.

Comment: See https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to follow the file structure for it to work. For the main user/organization site, use the `master` branch. For project sites, use `gh-pages`. You'd also have to put your index.html in the root folder. You can get more info at https://pages.github.com/

The problem you're not seeing your page is that you're missing index.html in the root folder. Move index.html of the `web_files` folder and fix the paths referenced in your page.